# Get the first two numbers of a string

Tags: java, performance, strings

**What would be the best way to get the first two numbers of a string?**

I can do it like this:

```
public static String getFirstTwoNumbersOfString(String s){
        if(s == null)
            return "";

        String numbers = "0123456789";

        String result = "";

        for(int i=0; i<s.length() && result.length()<2; i++){
            String c = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
            if(numbers.contains(c)){
                result += c;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But I think there must be a better way, more concise and with better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you can:

```
public static String getFirstTwoNumbersOfString2(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2); // Capacity of 2 chars.

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            sb.append(c);

            if (sb.length() == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Above you can nicely ask `Character` whether a given character is a digit. Also, `StringBuilder.append` runs in constant amortized time unlike string concatenation which will build a copy of two concatenated strings.

Hope that helps.