# Get the last two digits of a string

Tags: java, performance, strings

**What would be the most performant way to get the last 2 digits of a string?**

For example: `getLastTwoDigits("a1b2cd3e4ghi5jk")` must return `"45"`;

I had already asked [how to get the first two digits of a string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165495/get-the-first-two-numbers-of-a-string). But now I need a performant way to get the last two digits.

I've adapted the answer I received in the other question and I could make it work using the code below. However, I know that I've defeated the purpose of StringBuilder when I used `sb.insert(0, char)`.

```
private static String getLastTwoDigits(String s) {
    if(s==null)
        return null;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2);

    char charArray[] = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = charArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (Character.isDigit(charArray[i])) {
            sb.insert(0, charArray[i]);
            if (sb.length() == 2)
                break;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

I imagine that StringBuider is not the right tool for this case. So what would be the most performant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about performance until you've ***proved*** that you have a performance problem. Make your code readable and maintainable. A stream would solve this nicely.

```
Stream<char> digits = 
    s.toCharArray().stream()
    .filter(c -> Character.isDigit(c));

Stream<String> end = digits.skip(digits.size() - 2)
        .map(c -> Character.toString(c));

return end.collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Or with a little syntax sugar to make it a little less verbose.

```
Stream<char> digits = 
    s.toCharArray().stream()
    .filter(Character::isDigit);

return digits.skip(digits.size() - 2)
        .map(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

*Untested. May not compile.*

Comment: FYI - `Stream<char>` won't work. Use `Stream<Character>`, as generics do not support primitives as type arguments.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>             sb.insert(0, charArray[i]);
>             if (sb.length() == 2)
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return sb.toString();
> ```

You could change this to

```
             sb.append(charArray[i]);
             if (sb.length() >= digitCount) {
                 break;
             }
         }
     }

     return sb.reverse().toString();
```

Then you're using your `StringBuilder` as intended.  Appending rather than constantly inserting.

Changing `2` to `digitCount` allows you to alter the number of digits to find easily.

I prefer to always use the block form of control structures, even when the statement form would work.

Answer (score 2):

Your question involves two tasks, extracting digits and reversing their order.  One of the standard ways to reverse the order of something is to use a stack, which is a LIFO (Last In First Out) structure.  Go through the target string, rejecting non-digits and putting digits on the stack.  Then pop the last two entries off the top of the stack.  I have added extra code to deal with the cases of only one digit or no digits.

In general it is not good to return `null` from any method; it is better to throw an exception.  I am not sure if you have covered exceptions yet, but when you do you should return to this code and use them in place of the two `null` returns.

As a very minor point, your first `if` omitted the space between the `if` and the first parenthesis.  Omitting the space indicates a method call. With language structures: `if`, `for` etc. distinguish them by including the space as a separator.

```
import java.util.Stack;

private static String getLastTwoDigits(String s) {

    if (s == null) {
        return null;  // or throw exception.
    }

    // 1. Extract the digits.
    Stack<Character> digiStack = new Stack<>();

    char charArray[] = s.toCharArray();
    for (Character c : charArray) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            digiStack.push(c);
        }
    }

    // 2. Return last two digits in original order.
    if (digiStack.size() >= 2) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2);

        sb.append(digiStack.pop());
        sb.append(digiStack.pop());

        return sb.reverse().toString();
    } else if (digiStack.size() == 1) {
        return digiStack.pop().toString();
    } else {
        // No digits found.
        return null;  // or throw exception.
    }

} // end getLastTwoDigits()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get out the minimum of executed machine instructions, you should go the following route, which replaces the StringBuilder with an array `digits` and an index `di` into that array.

The array is filled from the end to the beginning, and the index always points behind the next free element of the array.

```
String getLastTwoDigits(String s) {
  char[] digits = new char[2];
  int di = 2;
  for (int si = s.length() - 1; si >= 0; si--) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      di--;
      digits[di] = c;
      if (di == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return new String(digits, di, 2 - di);
}
```

To see whether the generated machine code is really worth to write this complicated low-level code, look at the generated machine code using `+XX:PrintAssembly`, comparing it with the other solutions. And measure the execution time in a reliable benchmark (JMH).

Answer (score 1):

This compiles.
Generics do not support primitives.
Arrays do not have a method stream().
Streams do not have a method size().
Sadly toString() is ambiguous on Character.

```
List<Character> digits = s.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
            .filter(Character::isDigit)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

String lastTwoDigits = digits.stream()
            .skip(digits.size() - 2)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
```